# execl in Windows10 (C language) opens new window underneath all others

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Trying to make a "patcher" kind of program to launch a game. The thing patches updated files, if any, then launches the game.

It uses the execl() call to replace the current process by the game's one. It all works wonders, except the game window ends up underneath all other existing windows, and if there are no others, it starts with no focus. Very annoying.  This is under Window 10.

I've tried a million WINAPI things to try to focus the window from the game application itself, to no avail.

Am I missing something?

The game program is launched through execl().
The window is created through SDL_CreateWindow().
SDL_RaiseWindow() seems to do nothing, just like SwitchToThisWindow(), BringWindowTotop() or SetForeGroundWindow(). These functions seemed to look nice, but none of them did anything at all.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: `execl()` on Windows does not *replace* a process, as it does on Linux. It just spawns a *new* process and *kills* the current process. So you may as well just use `CreateProcess()` instead to start the game process, and let the patcher process exit gracefully.

Comment: This worked.

Using CreateProcess() along with the above functions (SwitchToThisWindow(), BringWindowTotop() or SetForeGroundWindow()), as well as SetWindowPos(TOPMOST), did the trick.